# Generating fixed length sequence of numbers bounded by k that add up to n

Tags: python, algorithm, math, random, integer

Given positive integers `l`, `k` and `n`, I am interested in writing a function `f(l, k, n)`, that returns a randomly generated sequence of length `l` of integers in `-k, -k + 1, ..., -1, 0, 1, ..., k - 1, k` that add up to `n`.

Any ideas how one could achieve this?

EDIT: Repetition is allowed. Ideally the probability distribution would be uniform on the set of solutions, but I'm not very worried about it: I am more interested in getting a unique solutions everytime the function is called.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You have to be more specific by what you mean by "random". One could come up with a trivial solution which picks two numbers at random, a third one to make the sum `n`, and the remaining `l-3` equal to 0.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Repetition is permitted. Ideally the probability distribution would be uniform, but I'm not very worried about it: I am more interested in getting unique sequences everytime I run it. If no such sequences is possible, the function should return None -- although with the values l, k and n I am planning to use, there will always be multiple solutions.

Comment: FWIW this problem seems to be related to linear Diophantine equations in multiple variables and the subset sum problem; a web search on these terms will find many resources. About generating random solutions, how about solving first the problem with nonintegers between, say, -1 and 1, and then rescaling and taking integer parts and adjusting the results to add up to n.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Actually, this question can be reduced to the other one. If you are looking for a sequence x_1, x_2, ..., x_l that adds up to n with -k<= x_i <= k, then you could instead look for a sequence y_1, y_2, ..., y_l that adds up to n + l*k, with 0<= y_i <= k. Then, you set x_i = y_i - k.

Comment: @user139019: My point was that none of the answers in the linked item take into account `x_i <= k` or `y_i <= k`. The comment by getglad under the answer by Mark Dickenson asks for code that takes a "high threshold" into account, but there was no such answer. A routine could do one of the linked answers then reject the list if any item were too large then try again, but that could mean many rejections in some problems. Would that kind of solution be good enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have clarified your question, I can give you an answer. However, since you still have not shown any work of your own, I'll just give you some ideas and an overall high-level algorithm. If you want more details, first show some of your own work.

As I implied in my comment, it may be that there is no possible desired sequence. For example, it is impossible to get a sequence of `3` numbers from `-2, -1, 0, 1, 2` to add up to `7`. You should check for that first. Even if there are possible sequences, there may be limitations on the first number in the sequence. If you want a sequence of `3` numbers from `-2, -1, 0, 1, 2` to add up to `5`, the first number cannot be `-2`. The minimum for your first number is then `1` and the maximum is `2`.

So here is an algorithm, after your initial check that any sequence is possible. Find the minimum and maximum possible values for the first number in the sequence. Choose a random number between those two values--use `randint` or `randrange` from the `random` module. Then subtract that number from your value of `n` and subtract `1` from `k` (the count of numbers still needed in your sequence). Iterate this until the sequence is complete (the count of numbers still needed is zero).

This will not choose all such sequences with uniform probability, but each such sequence is possible. You could equalize the probabilities somewhat by doing a `shuffle` on the sequence at the end. There are some minor optimizations that could be done but the way I explained it is simple.